# Executing function_pointer stored in a hashtable using qlibc causes segfault

Tags: c

I am storing a function pointer within a hashtable using qlibc. When I retrieve the function pointer from the hashtable and try to execute the function I get a segfault.  I have a feeling that the size I am specifying when I place the function pointer in the hashtable is possibly wrong?

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <qlibc/qlibc.h>

typedef struct my_struct_t MyStruct;

void my_function(void)
{
    printf("Executing my function!\n");
}

typedef void (my_f_ptr)(void);

struct my_struct_t
{
    my_f_ptr *my_func_ptr;
};

int main(void)
{    
    MyStruct *ms = malloc(sizeof(MyStruct));

    ms->my_func_ptr = my_function;


    qhashtbl_t *ht = qhashtbl(0,0);
    int ret = ht->put(ht, "func", ms->my_func_ptr, sizeof(my_f_ptr));
    int size = (int)ht->size(ht);
    my_f_ptr *data = ht->get(ht, "func", NULL, false);

    data();  <---SEGFAULT HERE

    free(ms);
    return 0;
}
```

ret is true and the size of the hashtable is 1 so something has been added.

If I try and place the whole structure in the hashtable using the following code, everything is fine:

```
int ret = ht->put(ht, "func", ms, sizeof(MyStruct));
MyStruct *data = ht->get(ht, "func", NULL, false);
data->my_func_ptr();
```

but that is not what I want. I need to store the function pointer.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think you want `sizeof(my_f_ptr*)` in the `put` call.

Comment: Please provide `struct my_struct_t`

Comment: Is `my_f_ptr` the type of `my_func_ptr`? Please show us.

Comment: struct my_struct_t can be found above in the code it is:
struct my_struct {
    my_f_ptr *my_func_ptr;
};

Comment: yes my_f_ptr is the type of my_func_ptr

Comment: @aschelper sizeof(my_f_ptr*) did not fix it unfortunately....still causes segfault

Comment: Isn't the typedef missing a `*`? For me, `sizeof` returns 1 for the typedef, and 8 for the actual pointer. When using `typedef void (*my_f_ptr)(void)`, both return 8. What's `sizeof(my_f_ptr)` for you?

Comment: @KarstenKoop, `sizeof(my_f_ptr)` is 1 for me also. using `typedef void (*my_f_ptr)(void)` and changing `data()` to `(*data)()` I still get a segfault